# Difficulty with importing txt file into R

Tags: r, import, readr

I'm currently trying to import a txt file into R, and neither read.table, read_table or read_table2 worked. With read.table, I just got an error that there were more columns than data. With read_table I got two columns of data, and with read_table2 I got too many columns split in a way that made no sense, with columns and data fields split up as per the image below.

This is a sample of the headers and first lines from the txt file:

> Blockquote Source Generator   Generator Identifier    Created Timestamp   Created Date    Recorded Timestamp  Recorded Date   Visit ID    URL ID  Referrer ID Domain  Protocol    URL Title   Top Domain  Search Terms    Transition Type Timestamp   Date
>
> Blockquote 27-strong-rooks-knitted-patiently  Web Historian - Community Edition/1.3.6 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36   web-historian   1517096769  2018-01-27T23:46:09.773127+00:00    1527424157  2018-05-27T12:29:17.479092+00:00    96844       0   american.edu    https   https://engage.american.edu/learn/login/index.php

This is an image of what the result was with read_table2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS6KT.png)

Thanks!

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is happening given the sample above.  `read_table` is using whitespace to separate the columns, thus every space is causing a new column being created.  Most likely the files are comma or delimitated so I would try using `read_csv` or `read_tsv` and see if this provides better results

Comment: You should  try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your own attempt and show it to us.